# Create list of lists from a list while changing one and always different value Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, int

I have a list of 9 integers with values 1, -1, 0 such as:

```
[-1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0]
```

What I am trying to do is that from this one list create list of lists where each one of them contain only one change and all the time different. For each -1 I want to change it into 0.

**Example:**

From the list:

```
[-1,0,0,1,-1,-1,1,1,0],
```

I want to get the result:

```
[ [ 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0]
, [-1, 0, 0, 1,  0, -1, 1, 1, 0]
, [-1, 0, 0, 1, -1,  0, 1, 1, 0]
]
```

So each list has only one value changed and each has a different one. I have no idea how to even start.

Comment: Start as you always do in Haskell: with a type signature. After that, try writing the dumbest possible function with that type signature, leaving blanks for yourself in places where you don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you always need is to figure out the type signature of your function. In your case you want

```
lister :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
```

Then, as you want to loop through the list but keeping track of the indexes you have changed, an easy way would be to list a list of your list (hard to follow, just look at the code) and then zip it with its index. Then for each list you switch the element in that position. This is you code

```
lister :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
lister ls = [switch i l | (i,l) <- zip [0..9] (repeat ls)]
```

You then need a switch function, to switch the element in the ith position accordingly to your rule:

```
switch :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
switch 0 ls = ls
switch n ls = [if i == n && x == -1 then 0 else x | (i,x) <- zip [1..] ls]
```

Note that this returns 9 lists, one for each element in your original list. Therefore it contains some duplicates. You can eliminate them using `nub` from `Data.List`, watch out because it is `O(n^2)`

This is your complete code:

```
import Data.List

lister :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
lister ls = nub [switch i l | (i,l) <- zip [0..9] (repeat ls)]

switch :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
switch 0 ls = ls
switch n ls = [if i == n && x == -1 then 0 else x | (i,x) <- zip [1..] ls]
```

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I think it's a bad question, but you can't really guess whether someone is a "help vampire" after a single question. This is why I chose to write my own answer in a way that is correct, and hopefully interesting to other spectators who might see the question, but obviously useless as a copy/paste homework solution.

Comment: @amalloy I think I didn't word my comment very well. I'm more concerned with, and was referring to, the site as a whole. Imagine what we would become if we indulged every lazy question that clearly is looking for someone else to do the work?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly this is a very specific problem. It is often useful to look at the bigger picture: what more general problem is this a special case of? Clearly, here, we are looking through a list, and may see an element that we wish to replace, in zero or more ways. Further, we wish to see how many ways it is possible to make a limited number of such replacements. So, let us implement the general case before thinking about how to specialize to our original problem:

```
import Control.Applicative (Alternative, empty, (<|>))

replaceNTimes :: Alternative f => (a -> f a) -> Int -> [a] -> f [a]
replaceNTimes _ 0 xs = pure xs
replaceNTimes _ _ [] = empty
replaceNTimes f n (x:xs) = replaceHere <|> keepLooking
  where replaceHere = (:) <$> f x <*> replaceNTimes f (n - 1) xs
        keepLooking = (x:) <$> replaceNTimes f n xs
```

If we have a "budget" of zero replacements remaining, we simply return the remainder of the list. If we have budget remaining but the list is empty, we abort, because we failed to make the expected number of replacements. Otherwise, we consult our replacement-suggester function to see which replacements are legal at the current position, and choose to either make one of them and recurse with a smaller N, or to make none and recurse with the same N.

With this tool at our disposal, the original problem is easy: we just specialize N to 1 (make exactly one replacement), and supply a replacing function that only suggests replacing -1 with 0:

```
replaceSingleNegativeOneWithZero :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
replaceSingleNegativeOneWithZero = replaceNTimes go 1
  where go (-1) = [0]
        go _ = []
```

And test to ensure that we get the expected output:

```
*Main> replaceSingleNegativeOneWithZero [-1,0,0,1,-1,-1,1,1,0]
[ [0,0,0,1,-1,-1,1,1,0]
, [-1,0,0,1,0,-1,1,1,0]
, [-1,0,0,1,-1,0,1,1,0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another try:

```
zeros :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
zeros _ []     = []
zeros h (x:xs) = [h ++ newX:xs] ++ zeros nextH xs
    where newX = if x == (-1) then 0 else x
        nextH = h ++ [x]

switch xs = ((filter (/= xs)) . (zeros [])) xs
```

Usage:

```
main = print $ switch [-1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: I believe you do not need the `nub` if you already checked they're different from the original one

Comment: @Lorenzo. Thank you. You are right! I will change that